# Option variables handling with jQuery in select change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I tried to write some jQuery functions to change some variables values when options of a select item are selected (add a certain value if option is selected, subtract that value if option is not selected anymore), but it adds and subtracts values in a very odd way. Here's the code I wrote for the javascript (adapted from a previous code that used to work with checkboxes):

```
var pds1=0;
var pds2=0;
var pds3=0;
var pdstot=0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#perk1').html(pds1);
  $('#perk2').html(pds2);
  $('#perk3').html(pds3);
  $('#perktot').html(pdstot);

  $("#blabla").change(
    function() {
      if ($("option#5:selected").length)
      {
        pds1=pds1+10;
        pdstot=pdstot+10;
      }
      else if(pds1>0)
      {
        pds1=pds1-10;
        pdstot=pdstot-10;
      }

      if ($("option#3:selected").length)
      {
        pds2=pds2+10;
        pdstot=pdstot+10;
      }
      else if(pds2>0)
      {
        pds2=pds2-10;
        pdstot=pdstot-10;
      }

      if ($("option#4:selected").length)
      {
        pds3=pds3+10;
        pdstot=pdstot+10;
      }
      else if(pds3>0)
      {
        pds3=pds3-10;
        pdstot=pdstot-10;
      }
      //option 6 adds 10 to variable pds1 and pds2
      if ($("option#6:selected").length)
      {
        pds1=pds1+10;
        pds2=pds2+10;
        pdstot=pdstot+10;
      }
      else if(pds1>0)
      {
        pds1=pds1-10;
        pds2=pds2-10;
        pdstot=pdstot+10;
      }

      $('#perk1').html(pds1);
      $('#perk2').html(pds2);
      $('#perk3').html(pds3);
      $('#perktot').html(pdstot);
    });
});
```

and here's the html

```
<select id='blabla' multiple='multiple'>
<option id='5'>Name5</option>
<option id='3'>Name3</option>
<option id='4'>Name4</option>
<option id='6'>Name6</option>
</select>

<span id="perk1"></span>
<span id="perk2"></span>
<span id="perk3"></span>
<span id="perk4"></span>
```

Can someone explain me how this function is handling variables?
Odd behavior example: clicking option 5 doesn't add 10 to pds1, but instead it subtracts 10 to pds2; what I'd like to happen instead it's to add 10 to pds1 and do nothing to pds2. I think the problem, in this case, it's in the "else if" under "option#6:selected", but why? And it's not the only odd behavior.

Comment: Quick tip for your next question: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Your options don't have id but your doing this?? `option#4`

Comment: sorry, my mistake pasting and editing the code: they have id! i edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see why you get the results you are getting. Using current code and the #5 example walk through each of the `if` statements. Since #5 is selected `pds1` gets 10 added. Since #6 isn't selected and pds1 got increased by #5 the `else` subtracts what was just added to pds1.

You can simplify this whole logic by simply resetting the variables to zero each time, and then only adding what is needed.

```
/* utilty function to avoid repeated lines */
function showValues(pds1, pds2, pds3) {

    var pdstot = pds1 + pds2 + pds3
    $('#perk1').html(pds1);
    $('#perk2').html(pds2);
    $('#perk3').html(pds3);
    $('#perk4').html(pdstot);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    showValues(0, 0, 0);

    $("#blabla").change(

    function() {
        var num_selected = $(this).find(':selected').length;

        var pds1 = 0;
        var pds2 = 0;
        var pds3 = 0;                     

        if ($("option#5:selected").length) {
            pds1 = pds1 + 10;
        }    
        if ($("option#3:selected").length) {
            pds2 = pds2 + 10;
        }    

        if ($("option#4:selected").length) {
            pds3 = pds3 + 10;
        }

        //option 6 adds 10 to variable pds1 and pds2
        if ($("option#6:selected").length) {
            pds1 = pds1 + 10;
            pds2 = pds2 + 10;    
        }

        showValues(pds1, pds2, pds3);

    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/f9UEC/